# node js res.render does not work, but res.send does

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am setting up the environment for a node js app. But the views/ejs files are not being rendered. 
If i do:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){

     res.send('Hello');
 });
```

it works.
But if i do:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){

   res.render("welcome");
});
```

it doesn't.

my app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const indexRoutes = require("./routes/index");
const userRoutes = require("./routes/user");
const ejsLayouts = require("express-ejs-layouts");
const path = require("path");

 mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/userAuth", function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
 console.log("Connected to database");
  });

 //EJS
 app.set('view engine','ejs');
 app.use(ejsLayouts); 
 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

 app.set('views',path.join(__dirname+'/views'))

 //ROUTES
 app.use("/", indexRoutes);
 app.use("/user", userRoutes);

 app.listen(3000, function() {
      console.log("server started");
  });
```

my index.js file (userLogin/routes/index.js)

```
  const express=require("express");
  path = require('path');
  router= express.Router();

  router.get("/",function(req,res){
     res.render("welcome");

   });

  module.exports = router;
```

my folder structure

userLogin

/..

/routes

```
   /index.js
```

/views

```
   /welcome.ejs
```

I have an h1 element olny in welcome.ejs file.

Comment: In `index.js` you are trying to render `check` where does that come from? Shouldn't you be rendering `welcome`?

Comment: You need to define the rendering engine with `app.engine()`. I don't know express-ejs-layouts but if it's a regular express templating engine you need to change from `app.use(ejsLayouts);` to `app.engine(ejsLayouts);`

Comment: `app.set('view engine', 'ejs');` is correct for ejs and `app.use(ejsLayouts);` isn't strictly required.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you provided, in `index.js` you are trying to render a view called `check`, when the only view you have is called `welcome`. Your paths and routes look to be correct, rendering the correct view should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
```

if u woudlike to render .html files

then

```
fs.readFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/../public/views/logs.html'), 'utf-8', (err, content) => {
    let renderedHtml = ejs.render(content, {'user': req.session.db}); //get redered HTML code
    res.end(renderedHtml);
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your respponse, but this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

you should have `views/layouts/layout.ejs` file if you are using [express-ejs-layouts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ejs-layouts) npm

inside app.js :

```
const ejs =require('ejs');
const ejsLayouts = require("express-ejs-layouts");

app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.use(ejsLayouts); 
app.set('layout', 'layouts/layout');
```

`layout.ejs` file has common layout that follow all files

if you are using bootstrap then your `layout.ejs` file would be like :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <title></title>
</head>

<body>

        <?- body ?>

</body>

</html>
```

so now other ejs pages will only have content to display

like `welcome.ejs` file is

```
<h1>Welcome Page</h1>
```